# Spring WebFlux: Serve files from controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Coming from .NET and Node I really have a hard time to figure out how to transfer this blocking MVC controller to a non-blocking WebFlux annotated controller? I've understood the concepts, but fail to find the proper async Java IO method (which I would expect to return a Flux or Mono).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/files")
public class FileController {

    @GetMapping("/{fileName}")
    public void getFile(@PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            InputStream in = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
            FileCopyUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the way to achieve that with Spring MVC should look more like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/files")
public class FileController {

    @GetMapping("/{fileName}")
    public Resource getFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(fileName);        
        return resource;
    }
}
```

Also, not that if you *just*  server those resources without additional logic, you can use Spring MVC's [static resource support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-caching-static-resources). With Spring Boot, `spring.resources.static-locations` can help you customize the locations.

Now, with Spring WebFlux, you can also configure the same `spring.resources.static-locations` configuration property to serve static resources.

The WebFlux version of that looks exactly the same. If you need to perform some logic involving some I/O, you can return a `Mono<Resource>` instead of a `Resource` directly, like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/files")
public class FileController {

    @GetMapping("/{fileName}")
    public Mono<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
        return fileRepository.findByName(fileName)
                 .map(name -> new FileSystemResource(name));
    }
}
```

Note that with WebFlux, if the returned `Resource` is actually a file on disk, we will leverage a [zero-copy mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) that will make things more efficient.

Comment: So, I would already benefit from WebFlux (zero-copy) with the first version? Further, I don't know where to get a fileRepository from? Could you provide a link to an example or doc? (I only know JPA repositories ...). Cheers!

Comment: You'll get zero-copy support for both, as long as the Resource is a file on disk (i.e. not something in-memory already or a file included in JAR). The `fileRepository` thing was an example for the use cases where you need actual logic. If you just need to serve resources, the first controller will work, or better, using the static resource support in Spring will be easier.

Comment: is it possible to make the static-locations read the file from disk every time without caching? I've changed some properties in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties with no luck.

Comment: actually, to be more specific - it caches the non-existence of the folder. if the folder it is mapped to appears after it, the app needs restarted to start reading from it again.